# use sscanf to read hexadecimal value from a string

Tags: c, hex

I want to read an Hex value from a string and store it a variable,
I am using `sscanf` but the original number is on 6 byte and I am only getting the least significant 4 bytes.

this is the code I am using :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char my_string[] ="\r\n0080254800DA 0x02 C\n0080254800DA 0x02 P\n9C04EB06ACA2 0x03 P";
    unsigned int a,b,c,d,e,f;
    char s1,s2,s3;
    sscanf(my_string, "\r\n%16x %X %c\n%16x %x %c\n%16x %x %c\n", &a, &b, &s1,&c,&d,&s2,&e,&f,&s3);
    printf("\r\n%#-X %#2x %c\n%#-X %#2x %c\n%#-X %#2x %c\n", a,b, s1,c,d,s2,e,f,s3);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the result I am getting:

0X254800DA 0x2 C

0X254800DA 0x02 P

0XEB06ACA2 0x3 P

how can I correct this ?

Comment: Find the value for `UINT_MAX` for your c-implementation.

Comment: I am testing on an online IDE https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_compiler.php

Comment: but this will be running on nucleo l053r8, I do not know haw to access that value

Comment: The board does not matter. `UINT_MAX` is in the C language, on any board. You just `#include <limits.h>` and `printf("%d\n", UINT_MAX)`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using 32bits sized integers.
To store a 12 characters hexadecimal integer, you need bigger than a 32bit type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* this include defines [u]int[8|16|32|64]_t types */
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    const char my_string[] ="\r\n0080254800DA 0x02 C\n0080254800DA 0x02 P\n9C04EB06ACA2 0x03 P";

    /* use Unsigned INTeger on 64 bits */
    uint64_t a, b, c, d, e, f;
    char s1,s2,s3;

    /* sscanf/printf formatting need some +l to handle such types */
    sscanf(my_string, "\r\n%16lx %lX %c\n%16lx %lx %c\n%16lx %lx %c\n", &a, &b, &s1,&c,&d,&s2,&e,&f,&s3);
    printf("\r\n%#-lX %#2lx %c\n%#-lX %#2lx %c\n%#-lX %#2lx %c\n", a,b, s1,c,d,s2,e,f,s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on [gcc-tio](https://tio.run/##hY9Ra4MwFIXf/RUXxWDhuqbqpKPbwLm9962DOUqaqBVsOowOx9hfn0t06xgUlpebcy5851zul5wPg1NJXncih2vViup4sb@1/lqyNZ6lJxxYJb3XYyVm8G6BfvwoVQt8zxo4vG1V21SyfHqGGztrMknpkgaX0ZLS@wRoTwNIz5nrTF6lNHq4o3GSJoExQ1jbqzFgPu@kqkqZCzAFGO6Qo8Aci2nfaTeOtmYDOwSOIBByhO/12EwtUAWowslSijNZeKe6CGNZdxHXPbj1I7j8V/VnlI1AdBrRcUSjCUcikOgEkiMp9C@cTUkvGt8W3oR3fIN2gh/kP1qHmFtNd3OvpuuT8YRu8rZrJNCV9TEMn7yoWakGf8Pq@gs)

Comment: (As a side note, to `scanf` and `printf` a `uint64_t` one should use `PRIx16` and `SCNx16` modifiers, but let's assume this code will work on most computers.)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes. That's why I linked to a test compiler which teels what modifier are needed.

Comment: A 64 *byte* integer is nonstandard. 64 *bit* seems more standard-conforming for `uint64_t`.

Comment: so the problem was that i am using variables with sizes that can not contain the variables I am trying to assign? How would you modify that code to make it work on every plateform ?

Comment: One would use the code matthieu posted, but substituted Ex. `"%16lx"` with `"%16" SCNx64`. See [inttypes.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). Using `uint64_t` is the most portable way of assuming your program will work the same on any platform (unless, you code on nucleo-l053 with newlib-nano enabled, and your printf implementation does not support uint64_t type. But that means that your platform is non-conformant. In that case, disable newlib-nano, if you use it)

Comment: @KamilCuk Not supporting `[u]intN_t` is permissible for a conforming c implementation.

Comment: Och, I wasn't clear there, newlib-nano does not support `printf("%lld", 1<<33);` and `PRId64` is defined as `"lld"` there. So the `printf` can't print `long long int`, and `uint64_t` is a typedef to `long long int`, so that way.